# How to localize error messages in data annotation in ASP.Net Boilerplate?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-localization

I'm using a project based on ASP.Net Boilerplate version 3.6.2 and ASP.Net Zero MVC (ASP.Net Core) template version 3.8.0. The method of localization is [described](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization) in the official documentation, but how to localize error messages in data annotation (Required, Range, MaxLength, etc.)?

Comment: Type `L("YourMessage")` in code

Comment: Feature request: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#1360](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1360)

Comment: @aaron thanks for your answer, but this has already lasts almost two years. I'm looking for an opportunity to do this now, rather than wait for developers to implement it.

Comment: @vivek_nuna this is don't work for data annotation.

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Core does this automatically for you as long as you add in the appropriate services:

```
services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcePath = "Resources");

...

services.AddMvc()
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

This works for all attributes since 1.1. However, validation attributes like `Required` were supported even before that.

Comment: I already opened the problem in the official repository. This is not currently supported "out of box". https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/issues/239

Comment: If it doesn't work with Boilerplate, then they *broke* it, because it's there out of the box in ASP.NET Core. Perhaps you should consider using Core directly. There may have been some benefit to something like Boilerplate with MVC, but I'm skeptical how much it actually buys you with Core.

Comment: Posted solution does not work with aspnet boilerplate / aspnetzero